# Can't add VSS 6.0 database in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-sourcesafe

I am using VSS 6.0 along with Visual Studio 2008. If I launch VSS separately, I can add a Database by clicking "Browse" -> "Browse" -> click on a "srcsafe.ini" file. I can then choose a name for the database, and it will be added to the list of available databases.

However, if I am running Visual Studio, and I try to add my solution to source control, it will prompt me to connect to a VSS database, for which I follow the exactly same procedure described as above. Instead of adding the database to the list of database, it will do nothing. No screen freeze, no error, no nothing.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? If yes, did you solve it and how did you solve it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: VSS 6 is **really old** now. Are you sure this will work on Windows 8, when MS stops making Windows 7 available late next year? Even if you don't want dvcs, you can still use SVN for free, and that includes VS integration via AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN.

Comment: My company uses VSS 6 so it is not up to me.

Comment: Not even VSS 2005, huh? They need to get off their keisters and get transitioned to something new, or they'll soon find themselves hamstrung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the solution here and see if it helps you solve the problem:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/519319/using-visual-sourcesafe-6-0-with-visual-studio-2008-on-windows-7-x64